# How to test the disturbance effect of a measuring instrument?

Tags: t-test, experiment-design, accuracy, ancova, reliability

I am trying to think of an experimental design that allows me to test to what extent a measuring tool (automatic counting unit) alters (by restricting the entrance area) the measured quantity (number of bumblebees entering a nest).

For this, I plan to count manually the number of entering bees in four bumblebee colonies, half of these colonies will be equipped with the automatic counting unit. Then, I would repeat the process several times but alternate which colonies are equipped with the counting unit so that all colonies will have been equipped exactly half of the time with a unit.

In a statistical analysis I will the compare colonies with and without the unit installed. I think I would e.g. use a t-test to see if there was a general difference or an ANCOVA with testing round as independent variable to see if the difference between colonies with and without units changed over time (bees may get used to the counters).

**1. Are there any general recommendations on how to evaluate disturbance
    effects of measuring tools?**

**2. Does the proposed experimental set up make
    sense?**

Comment: Search this site (and other sources) for "calibration."  There's a large literature on this (chemometrics and envirometrics).

Comment: Thanks for the comment. As far as I can see this relates only to the part of the question  on accuracy. The main reason for my question was however that I am unsure how the evaluate the disturbance effect. We are trying to test automatic counting units that count the number of bumblebees entering/leaving a nest, but the counting units restrict also the entrance / exit area and may therefore not only make erroneous measurements but actually affect the number of bees leaving/entering the nest.

Comment: Therein lies the difficulty with multi-part questions.  Please edit your post to focus on a *single* question of interest.

Comment: I have edited the question with a clearer focus on the disturbance effect. I have still written two questions, which are however basically the same questions except that one is in general and the other for my specific case. I can rephrase it to one if needed/recommended.

Comment: Thank you (+1).  It still is a calibration problem.  Your research on calibration of measurement systems ought to turn up extensive information about how to design a calibration study, thereby answering #1.